# Share USB external drive between multiple users on same PC

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, hard-drive, samba

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 20.10 on a Dell PC.  I have a USB external drive that I would like to share between multiple users on the same computer.  The drive is mounted at /media/myname/audio.  When I switch users, I can see the drive; however, I cannot open it.  I have the permissions set on the drive as: user=rwe, group=rwe, others=r.  I have turned sharing on using the drive properties, and have samba installed.  I have added the line in the smb.conf file "force user = myname".  (Of course, myname is my real username).  However, I still cannot open the drive.  What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1):

> I have turned sharing on using the drive properties, and have samba
> installed.

Although Samba is used to share folders across the network not between local users on the same system I suppose you could make this work - although it would be somewhat convoluted:

Have each of your users connect to your share by entering in the locatoion bar of your file manager:

```
smb://localhost/audio
```

A more traditional approach is just to change your mount point from **/media/myname/audio** to **/media/audio**. This prevents /media/myname acting as a gate that allows only "myname" to traverse that folder to get to what is beyond it.